# Eclipse RCP plugin inheritance

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I am creating an Eclipse RCP application and have multiple plugins that share the same menus and commands. Is it possible to have the plugins extend one central plugin so that I don't have to program the same menus and commands for each plugin that uses them? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: A plug-in does not have a menu - only windows, views and editors do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Plugins are not extending other plugins, they depend on each other.
Please re-phrase your question.

Comment: A plug-in can contribute a menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let your "annex" plugins **depends** on the central one (exporting required packages).

Answer (score 0):

Add  menu-command-handler of eclipse, actionSet is outdated